# ffmpeg not detecting video file duration

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

Am using the following code to detect video duration before uploading using ffmpeg, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php
  $file=sample.avi;
  $time = exec("$ffmpeg -i /path/".$file." 2>&1 | 
  grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//");
  echo $time;
?>
```

I need to echo video duration as text input to sql before uploading file to server.

Comment: Please, provide output from `ffmpeg -i file_name` command.

Comment: Remove the PHP complexity and see if it works with `ffmpeg` manually in cli first. If it works, the issue is with your script, if it does not work, then it will be easier to debug without the extra PHP junk in the way. That being said, using `ffprobe` to do this is much better. I will show you how once you confirm if the scripting itself is the issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

with following code to retrive video duration

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mUri);
String time = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
int VideoDuration = Integer.parseInt(time);
mmr.release();
```